# Set default avatar network-wide

Tags: multisite, avatar

I've seen plugins and snippets on how to set a new default avatar for a site.  I'm wondering if this can be done network-wide, such that every new site on the network will have the network's avatar as its primary default. from there the plugin's that allow the user to upload a new avatar will be sufficient to let each site define it's own.  But until they do I'd prefer they have my avatar than the mystery man or some of the others which are downright ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mu-plugins folder I now have the following code, which adds a custom avatar as the default network wide, but allows each individual site to change it thereafter.

```
<?php
  /*
    Plugin Name: Network Default Avatar
    Description:  This Plugin sets the default avatar network-wide
    */

    class Network_Default_Avatars {

    // configure these two variables
    static $name = "Network Default";  // text description of avatar... ie "Mystery Man"
    static $avatar = "http://example.com/default-avatar.png";  // URL of avatar

    function __construct() {

        // default avatar
        add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', array( $this, 'default_avatar' ) );  
        add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', array( $this, 'new_blog_default_avatar' ) );

    }
    // add to list of default avatars
    function default_avatar ($avatar_defaults) {  
        $ib_avatar[self::$avatar] = self::$name;  
        return array_merge( $ib_avatar,$avatar_defaults ); // Put our custom avatar on top
    }

    // set a new blog to have the default avatar
    function new_blog_default_avatar( $blog_id ){
        switch_to_blog($blog_id);
        update_option( 'avatar_default', esc_url( self::$avatar ) );
        restore_current_blog();
    }

}

new Network_Default_Avatars();
```

**EDIT #1**
Per @Otto's comment about the `default_option_avatar_default_filter` I've changed the new blog `update_option` action to use the default filter instead.

```
<?php
  /*
    Plugin Name: Network Default Avatar
    Description:  This Plugin sets the default avatar network-wide
    */

    class Network_Default_Avatars {

    // configure these two variables
    static $name = "Network Default";  // text description of avatar... ie "Mystery Man"
    static $avatar = "http://example.com/default-avatar.png";  // URL of avatar

    function __construct() {

        // default avatar
        add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', array( $this, 'avatar_defaults' ) );  
        add_filter( 'default_option_avatar_default', array( $this, 'default_avatar' ) ); 

    }

    // add to list of default avatars
    function avatar_defaults ($avatar_defaults) {  
        $ib_avatar[self::$avatar] = self::$name;  
        return array_merge( $ib_avatar,$avatar_defaults ); // Put our custom avatars on top
    }


    function default_avatar () {  
        return self::$avatar; 
    }

}

new Network_Default_Avatars();
```

Answer (score 6):

The avatar_default is the better option.

```
add_filter('pre_option_avatar_default', 'se72578_avatar_default');
function se72578_avatar_default( $option ){
   return 'http://example.com/your/default/here.jpg';
}
```

Simple. Stick that in a mu-plugin and you're good to go.

Edit: If you want to still allow site owners to change the default avatar, use the `default_option_avatar_default` hook instead.

Comment: Thanks Otto.  My problem with this is that it precludes the individual site owners from ever being able to change or create their own defaults.

Comment: Okay, in that case, you just use the default_option_avatar_default hook instead. Then the code will apply for the "default", which is the case where they have not created their own avatar setting yet.

Comment: Well neat. Learned something new about the `default_option_$option` filter. Works great on the front end, but doesn't appear in the Discussion settings and can never be reverted to. I kind of like my solution for not confusing the individual site admins.

Comment: Well, if you want to add to the options then there's other filters you can use too. Filters are better than overriding the entire function, no matter how you slice it.

Comment: I didn't think I was overriding an entire function, just setting an option on new blog creation.  Would you take a look at my updated solution? I am using the `default_option_avatar_default` in conjunction with `avatar_defaults` filter.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yeah, that method works fine.

Answer (score 5):

[Must Use Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) will anable functionality global. And actualy functionality is pretty simple... only prefiltring **default_avatar** value.

Use this code as plugin which you can install to anable default avatar.

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Network Default Avatar
    Description:  This Plugin Used to be the General Framework
    Author: 
    Version: 
    Author URI:
    */

    add_filter('pre_option_avatar_default', 'pre_option_avatar_default');
    function pre_option_avatar_default(){
        return 'mystery';
    }
```

**Update**  New code

1. Using get_avatar filter hook you can replace the original avatar

   ```
   add_filter('get_avatar', 'get_avatar_custom',10,5);
   function get_avatar_custom($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt){
      // your code here...
         /*
         ** Example code will check if current avatar string is contain "mystery" avatar if yes, it will 
         ** try to get site_default_avatar property from options table (you can create a UI for entering this value)
         ** if system_default_avatar exists - filter will repalce default value (first argument of this filter callback)
         ** and return new value
         ** if (strpos($avatar, '561e2e7a9910204ba43fa4097e45c5e9') !== false 
         **    && get_option('site_default_avatar', false) != ''){
         **    $avatar =  "<img alt='".esc_attr($alt)."' src='".get_option('site_default_avatar', false)."' 
         **        class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo avatar-default' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
         ** } 
         **
         */
       return $avatar;
   }
   ```
2. Using a... get_avatar function. get avatar is plugable function, which mean you can ovveride it in any plugin, theme or in our case in mu-plugin

   ```
   function get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false {
      // your code here
      return $some_html_with_avatar_picture; 
   }
   ```

Comment: +1 A real improvement would be to serve it from the media library and kill this slow HTTP request over to gravatar.com

Comment: get_avatar filter will allow you to do that...

Comment: From the question, I think this is exactly what was asked _"(...) I'd prefer they have my avatar than the mystery man or some of the others (...)"_

Comment: method same, usign filter "get_avatar" to change picture, all code to mu-plugin.

Comment: thanks @CodeMonkey re: `pre_option_` will the users be able to select their own option later? and re: filtering `get_avatar`... how does one filter this to only effect our default?  very annoying that WP puts a gravatar request in front of a local URL!

Comment: pre_option_$option ovveriding original value. so it never come to selection... so no users wouldn't be able to choose own default avatar's.

re: filtering <code>get_avatar</code> imagine that user dosn't have avatar so using filter (let's say you will search for mistery avatar url from gravatar service) you will be able to get info - if gravatar not match to default one return original $avatar variable if matchs... and return different html with img tag e.g. '<img src="default_avatar.png" />';  that general meaning of filters. choosing and filtrering, posibility to ovveride original settings.

Comment: So `pre_option_$option` is not a solution then, since I want each blog to be able to change to their own site-specific default.  I understand filters, but I am not following your explanation of how to filter `get_avatar` for only our custom default.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: Example added. If you want to create interface for your users to be able to add any of additional options to own options tables you can refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API page